# How to expose the control panel of the qt gui time sink?

Tags: gnuradio-companion, qtwidgets

I see here that there is a way to adjust the time div on this gui, but I cant figure out how to expose the controls.

https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/QT_GUI_Time_Sink

My gui looks like the first image, and has no settings exposed.  Their second image shows the settings exposed, and I would like to know how they did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the middle mouse button to expose some controlls. The last option in this drop down menu is "Control Panel", which is what you are looking for.